# What does "database" do in Quartus?

Tags: quartus

Quartus has settings to export/import database under the project drop-down box.

The project directory contains two folders named db and incremental_db.

What is this "database" and what does it contain?

Comment: usually components for BOM

Comment: could you elaborate please?

Comment: Databases in CAD software is often what they call the library of components for the BOM or perhaps simulation.

Comment: This question is about Altera/Intel Quartus Prime which is used with their FPGAs. It is not related to any schematic capture or PCB design tool.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not notice you said Quartus.

Answer (score 1):

The database is the internal representation of the project that is used by the compiler.

The `quartus_map` program reads input files and stores their contents in the database.

After all inputs are read, those components that were actually used are copied into a separate area inside the database that represents the entire project. On this representation, optimizations are performed, like propagation of constant signals and removal of unused outputs.

The `quartus_fit` program then takes this representation and finds a mapping to the actual hardware. This mapping is then written back into the database.

The `quartus_asm` program pulls the mapping data from the database and generates the programming files.

Because the format of the database is internal, it can be optimized quite well, which saves a bit of time during compilation.

The `incremental_db` is an additional database that contains information about file modification dates and where certain logic came from. This is used by the "Quick Recompilation" function to skip processing steps whose input hasn't changed.